# Crashing at listView item remove?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, listview, crash

I use the following to clear the whole listView

```
void Form1::button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    ActiveControl = tabControl1->SelectedTab;

    if (listView3->Items->Count == 0)
    {
        ::MessageBox(0, "Please select data.", "Failed to clear data.", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    else
    {
        listView3->Items->Clear();
    }
}
```

I then try to use the following to clear a selected item...but it crashes...

```
void Form1::listView3_ItemCheck(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::ItemCheckEventArgs^  e)
{
    listView3->Items[e->Index]->Remove();
}
```

What would I replace my remove function with so it doesn't crash?

EDIT: This is how I add to my listView3...

```
    ListViewItem^ subitem = gcnew ListViewItem();

    subitem->SubItems->Add(textBox2->Text);

    listView3->Items->Add(subitem);
```

Comment: Just check that the index exists in the Items list before you remove from the object.

Answer (score 0):

If the element at that index is a null reference you might have to use a different approach.

Try to use the RemoveAt feature of the collection of items, like so:

```
if (e->Index >= 0 && e->Index < listView3->Items->Count)
{        
    listView3->Items->RemoveAt(e->Index);
}
```

Comment: that crashes :(. Also your second edit is impossible at the line != 0

Comment: what about checking whether Items[e->Index] is null? Would that work?

Comment: Your second edit revised still crashes causing Microsoft Visual Studio to produce the error: http://privatepaste.com/ec161ab69c

Comment: Your third edit still crashes :( reproducing the same error result above.

Comment: So the exception is an "ArgumentOutOfRange".. Can you step through the code and see what index it's trying to remove and what is the state of the collection at that point?

Comment: I added my code on how I add to the listView3...and I will try.

Comment: The index it is trying to remove is '0' as it is the first item on the listView. It still crashes if I try to remove any other item above the index of 0, so let's say the 3rd item which would be a index of 2, it would still crash.